# Setting data-content of Bootstrap popover doesn't work

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap 3 popover defined to show when an icon is clicked in a table cell.  The table rows are inserted dynamically when the page loads.  My jQuery uses an Ajax call to get the contents of the popover.  When the popover is displayed, its title is present by its contents are empty.

Here's the relevant html:

```
<td>1-Year Individual <a tabindex="0" class="history-info" data-trigger="focus" data-memberid="123" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" data-title="Membership history for Fred Smith" data-html="true" data-content=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" style="color:grey;"></span></a></td>
```

As you can see, the data-content attribute is set to empty.

Here's my javascript.

```
$("#member-table .history-info").on("show.bs.popover", function () {
var memberid=$(this).data("memberid");
$.ajax({
    url: "memberships-GetHistoryInfo.php",
    type: "GET",
    data: {MemberID: memberid},
    datatype: "html",
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
        $(this).data("content",data);
    }
});
```

})

I have verified with an alert right after the $(this).data("content",data); line that the data-content is set to the expected value but nothing shows up in the popover except the title.

## member-table in the selector is the id of the table in question except the title.

Answer (score 0):

The [jquery.data() API](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) sets data for an element but is abstracted away by jQuery and sits in a layer above the DOM. I would consider adding the attribute with `$(this).attr('data-content', data);`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately, it made no difference.

Comment: Ah, I went on the bootstrap docs for popovers, grabbed the element in the example with jQuery in my browser console and changed the `data-content` attribute with `attr()`, clicked the button and the content had changed to what I had set it to - maybe you have to set the content before `show.bs.popover` fires? From the `.popover('show')` method docs at http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers, seems that's the point it checks for content. Instead, on page load could you get the data for all the popovers via ajax and loop over the result and add the data attribute to all the rows?

Comment: I couldn't find a jQuery popover example at the link you gave, maybe I just missed it.  I was originally creating the data-content for each icon at page load but performance was not great due to the number of rows in the table and the db accesses required.  My hope is to improve the performance by dynamically creating the data-content only when an icon is clicked.

Comment: If you scroll down a little there's a big red button that says "click to toggle popover". What are you using to build the markup for the table? presumably you must be looping over a dataset - can you include the text in the data and add the data-content attributes at the same time?

Comment: Been trying some other things. No luck yet but there's definitely something strange going one.  I added an id to the icon that displays the popover  and added the command alert($(this).attr("id")); right before I set the data-content - it came back undefined.  It's as if $(this) is not pointing to the right element, although it gets the correct value for data-memberid earlier in the script.  I'm about to try your suggestion of using the show method.

Answer (score 0):

Tumbled on this old question trying to solve a similar problem in Bootstrap 4.

I solved my issue by separating the moment where I showed the popover and the one when I update some of it, which had to be after the popover had reached/was instantiated inside the DOM. Separating the commands was enough for me.

In the OP there's also another issue though: the Ajax request returns [a promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). If you try and use the data immediately your code, which races faster than the promise, will have no usable data.

It suffices to use a `.then` at the end of the promise to make your code wait for the data to be available, e.g.:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
}).then( data => {
    // do something with the received data
});
```

Some examples are provided at the above link but promises are a rather wide subject, worth spending some quality time to understand them.

Cheers